# How do I avoid pyramid of doom - iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, coding-style, code-cleanup

I have a pyramid of doom in my code.

[image]

```
if places.count > 0 {

        for i in 0..<places.count {
            for j in 0..<places.count {
                if let nameI = places[i]["name"] {
                    if let cityI = places[i]["city"] {
                        if let nameJ = places[j]["name"] {
                            if let cityJ = places[j]["city"] {
                                if let latI = places[i]["lat"] {
                                    if let lonI =  places[i]["lon"] {
                                        if let latitudeI = Double(latI) {
                                            if let longitudeI = Double(lonI) {
                                                if let latJ = places[j]["lat"] {
                                                    if let lonJ =  places[j]["lon"] {
                                                        if let latitudeJ = Double(latJ) {
                                                            if let longitudeJ = Double(lonJ) {

                                                                if(i != j) {

                                                                    let coordinateI = CLLocation(latitude: latitudeI, longitude: longitudeI)
                                                                    let coordinateJ = CLLocation(latitude: latitudeJ, longitude: longitudeJ)

                                                                    let distanceInMeters = coordinateI.distance(from: coordinateJ) // result is in meters
                                                                    let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters/1609.344


                                                                    var distances = [Distance]()
                                                                    distances.append(Distance(
                                                                        distanceInMiles: distanceInMiles,
                                                                        distanceInMeters: distanceInMeters,
                                                                        places: [
                                                                            Place(name: nameI, city: cityI, lat: latitudeI, long: longitudeI, coordinate: coordinateI),
                                                                            Place(name: nameJ, city: cityJ, lat: latitudeJ, long: longitudeJ, coordinate: coordinateJ),
                                                                            ]
                                                                    ))
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I avoid it?

Is there a technique or rule I should follow?

In iOS, we have to use a lot of `if-let`. How would one avoid doing like me ?

Comment: Most of the code you posted is irrelevant to your question. Please only post relevant code.

Comment: I want them them to see the context of what I am trying to do. I will add the picture showing the part of the **pyramid of doom**.

Comment: How is all of the table view code relevant to your pyramid? How are those extensions relevant?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: nice horrible code for halloween :) maybe try to adopt [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) or google for some open source solutions like [`ObjectMapper`](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper) for json parsing.

Comment: @kyo don't overreact. Now you've removed too much. At least put back the relevant structures so we know what `places` is.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a first approximation. As you can see, there are lots of repeated patterns that can be extracted out.

```
for (i, placeDictI) in 0..<places.enumerated() {
    guard
        let nameI = placeDictI["name"],
        let cityI = placeDictI["city"],
        let latitudeI = placeDictI["lat"].map(Double.init),
        let longitudeI =  placeDictI["lon"].map(Double.init),
        else { continue  }

        let coordinateI = CLLocation(latitude: latitudeI, longitude: longitudeI)
        let placeI = Place(name: nameI, city: cityI, lat: latitudeI, long: longitudeI, coordinate: coordinateI)

    for (j, placeDictJ) in places.enumerated() where i != j {
        guard  let nameJ = placeDictI["name"],
            let cityJ = placeDictI["city"],
            let latitudeJ = placeDictI["lat"].map(Double.init),
            let longitudeJ =  placeDictI["lon"].map(Double.init)
            else { continue }


        let coordinateJ = CLLocation(latitude: latitudeJ, longitude: longitudeJ)
        let placeJ = Place(name: nameJ, city: cityJ, lat: latitudeJ, long: longitudeJ, coordinate: coordinateJ)

        let distanceInMeters = coordinateI.distance(from: coordinateJ) // result is in meters // Editor's note: REALLY? I would have thought that a variable called "distanceInMeters" would store volume in litres! Silly me!
        let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters/1609.344

        var distances = [Distance]()
        distances.append(Distance(
            distanceInMiles: distanceInMiles,
            distanceInMeters: distanceInMeters,
            places: [ placeI, placeJ ]
        ))
    }
}
```

Here are the transformations I applied:

1. Don't check for `places.count > 0`. If it's 0, the loop won't do anything.
2. For every `if` statement whose block fully encompasses its parent block, I replaced it with a `guard`.
3. Merged adjacent `guard` statements with a comma.
4. Expressed failable type conversions as `Optional.map(_:)` expressions, rather than as separate `let` clauses in the `guard` statement
5. Changed the `i != j` check into a `where` condition on the inner `for` loop.
6. Changed this pattern:

   ```
    for i in 0..<array.count {
        use(array[i])
        use(array[i])
        use(array[i])
        //...
    }
   ```

   to this pattern:

   ```
   for (i, element) in array.enumerated() {
        use(element)
        use(element)
        use(element)
        //...
    }
   ```

Seeing as there's no an obvious case of repetition, it's a good hint that the Dictionary unpacking into a `Place` belongs in a convenience initializer, that takes a dict that initailizes a `Place?` from it. Even better, just use the Codable system, and have the compiler synthesize it for you.